# What is the origin of "deah, binah, v'haskel"?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot

There are two nusachos with the fourth brocha in Shemoneh Esreh of which I am aware.  One, extant today in nusach Ashkenaz, certain nusach Sefard, and Teman Baladi, and present in very old siddurim, ends "deah, binah, v'haskel".  Why are these three words linked conceptually?

Strictly by way of comparison, other nusachos have "chochmah, binah, vadaas", which have a clear source in that they are three linked sefiros.

Comment: In fairness, I know of a third nusach that combines the two.

Comment: The former method is AFAIK a Nusach Sefard change.

Comment: See these: http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol12/v12n048.shtml#10, http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol12/v12n050.shtml#03

Comment: [Rambam's siddur](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/27.htm) and R Amram Gaon has the regular Nusach Ashkenaz version. Machzor Vitri seems to have two versions: one like Nusach Ashkenaz and one that adds Chochmah. I suspect the latter is a typo because a similar mistake appears in some printings of the Rambam.

Comment: Interesting http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25b02.htm#11

Comment: Yoel, do you want the origin (like the first Siddur to use it), or the textual/conceptual basis (like a Pasuk or reformulation of a series of Pesukim)?

Comment: @ba why? [15ch]

Comment: @msh210 If you're asking about the tag change from [tag:nusach-ashkenaz] to [tag:nuschaot], it's because the question asks about multiple texts (Ashkenaz and Chabad — but without specifying their names). But if you think it's better to put both the [tag:nusach-ashkenaz] and [tag:nusach-ari] or something else, I will defer.

Comment: I actually just saw that Double AA just posted something similar on meta.

Comment: @ba as far as I know "deah..." is specific to Ashkenaz whereas "chochmah..." is extant in all other nusachos, hence "nusach-Ashkenaz". I may be wrong though.

Comment: @SethJ the latter although it's interesting to note that it might have been universal prior to a certain point.

Comment: @yoel You seem to be correct based on sidurim at which I looked, but I edited it because you are comparing different texts (but, as I said, I will defer if someone else thinks a different tag or tag combination is better)

Comment: @ba the question is only about the _nusach Ashk'naz_ version.

Comment: @ba the comparison is only to make the point that "chochmah..." has a clear source in the sefiros. The question is really only on "deah..."

Comment: @msh210 It's also comparing nuscha'os. Maybe it should also have had that tag because it's mostly asking about that one. If you think so, I can edit it back in (or rather you could).

Comment: @msh210 No, the question is also about the _nusach Teman -- Baladi_ version. [see 'Arvith here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%5C%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_(%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%99))

Comment: So I support @ba's position.

Comment: @yoel Do you have any evidence that Chochmah Binah vaDaat is not a "later" Kabbalistic/Arizal adjustment to the Siddur? If you don't, then I'm not sure I follow how the comparison in the question strengthens your question. Deah Binah veHaskel is original and you can ask why the Anshei Keneset Hagedola chose it just as easily as you can ask why they chose lots of other words in Tefillah (which is fine as a question).

Comment: For a discussion of the significance of the nusach, refer to פרי מגדים אורח חיים משבצות זהב סימן קטו .

Comment: @DoubleAA it may well be.  It's totally irrelevant, though, as my question is only "what, if any, is the source of or meaning behind deah, binah, and haskel?"  I include chochmah, binah, and daas only to illustrate that they have a clear source in Kabalah.  Would the question be clearer if I removed the comparison?

Comment: As for the phrase's presence in Baladi, Rambam, and Rav Amram Gaon, it would seem that the evidence suggests deah... as widespread at a certain point historically.  Therefore perhaps the nusachos tag is entirely irrelevant here.

Comment: @yoel, does the set of words we have for the Sefirot significantly predate the Anshei Kenesset Hagedola? If not, I wouldn't consider it any more of a source than I would them.

Comment: @DoubleAA if the question is about a version the asker saw in a certain rite, though, then it's a question about that rite.

Comment: @msh210 Well, now he's seen it in both.

Answer (score 1):

[Avudraham](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&st=&pgnum=52&hilite=) explains that Deah and Haskel are based on the Posuk in [Jeremiah 3:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39870&st=&pgnum=26). The earliest source I can find is [Tana Davai Eliyahu](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49591&st=&pgnum=43&hilite=).

Comment: Ok...and it exists hundreds of years earlier in the Rambam, Seder Amram Gaon and Machzor Vitri as we already established above.

Comment: Also, the question did not seek "the origin (like the first Siddur to use it)," but rather it sought "the textual/conceptual basis (like a Pasuk or reformulation of a series of Pesukim)". So not sure how this answer the question.

Comment: @GershonGold (and Double AA) does my edit improve the question, and make it easier to provide an answer?

Comment: @yoel IMHO yes!

Comment: What exactly is Tana Devei Eliyahu the earliest source of? It says חכמה בינה דעה והשכל

Comment: Read again - it says ולבקש ממנו דעת ובינה והשכל

Comment: @GershonGold Oh I was looking a few lines below. Either way, Seder Rav Amram Gaon is earlier.

Comment: So what about binah?  Seems weird to stick it in between them if that's the source. I think it's also telling that binah is the one shared between nusachos.